# What are the advantages for an user that is running a Bitcoin full node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node

I am running a Bitcoin full node Bitcoin core version v0.19.1 (64-bit).

I know that is one of the most secure wallets, but the process to set up a full node is very painful, and even if you keep this full node running 24/7 you won't get paid.

So I just would like to know what are the advantages for an user that is running this full node, I only can think that the network will be benefit with that somehow, but I can't see any advantage for the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You validate your own UTXO without any external services that may play for your disadvantage, no middleman needed
2. It's the most privacy-preserving and secure way of using bitcoin. Lightweight-clients have some privacy issues, not too many people are reviewing their code.
3. The process of setting it up and using bitcoin core is a major step in one's education when it comes to bitcoin. More knowledge = advantage.
4. You have some voting power on consensus rules, like in UASF.